# Bluetooth GPS compatibility list for Android 2.2 / Archos 43 tablet?

Tags: gps, bluetooth, archos-gen8, external-gps

I've been looking at a very inexpensive bluetooth GPS ([DeLorme Earthmate BT-20](http://www.geeks.com/details.asp?invtid=BT-20&cpc=SCH)) to pair with my Archos 43 Internet Tablet running Android 2.2.  Is anyone aware of a compatibility list that I should be referencing when considering pairing my device with a bluetooth GPS?  I assume that the Android app will be used to reference maps, and the GPS will simply provide coordinates, but I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you need to worry about hardware compatibility beyond the BT specs.  Your A43IT uses Bluetooth 2.1 EDR so as long as the BT GPS supports that it should be all set.  You'll either need an internet connection to use Google maps, or like you were planning, an app that downloads the maps, like [CoPilot](http://www.appbrain.com/app/copilot-live-usa/com.alk.copilot.market.usa).

I haven't gotten around to buying one yet, but I've been doing some digging in preperation.  Here's some links that may help:

- [BlueGPS4Droid](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=833094) - App over at XDA that interfaces with the BT GPS
- [This guy is using his Nexus 1 to give his A70IT WiFi and GPS](http://forum.archosfans.com/viewtopic.php?f=73&t=42429&hilit=bluetooth+gps)
- Here's another [relevant thread](http://forum.archosfans.com/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=42219&p=294300&hilit=bluetooth+gps#p294300)... and [another](http://forum.archosfans.com/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=42852&hilit=bluetooth+gps).

Let me know what you end up doing and what works in case you beat me to the setup.

Answer (score 1):

Globalsat BT-359CS works fine with mine.  Watch the screen saver though.  If it kicks in the bluetooth connection gets messed up.

Answer (score 1):

I finally purchased a BTGP35KM and everything is fine. Also, I have discovered Google Labs Zone which enables downloading a 10 sq miles map on your Android, thus enabling offline (only found the french version [here](http://www.maximejohnson.com/techno/2011/07/tutoriel-comment-telecharger-des-cartes-sur-google-maps-android/)).